# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 10

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have dates in string format delimited with space, and I am trying to use datatime to convert them to dates so later on I can sort my data based on the name's column and date's column.Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
DATE = '1 nov 2010'
current_date = datetime.strptime(DATE, '%d %b %y')
print(current_date)
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DEL.py", line 4, in <module>: current_date = datetime.strptime(DATE, '%d %b %y')
File "lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime: tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "lib\_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime: 
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 10
```

I have checked all the previous questions on this topic and it seems none of them apply in this scenario as I do not have any hidden character or anything and it is as simple as typing the dates. Appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%y` parameter of `strptime` is ["Year without century"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). An uppercase `%Y` is what you need.